# Pegar o valor de uma variável em SeekBar - Java / Android

Tags: java, android

Sou iniciante em Java / Android e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com processamento de imagem. No momento já tenho a aplicação funcionando com os filtros necessários.

No caso tenho:

```
Canny(edges, edges, thresholdCanny, thresholdCanny2);
```

Gostaria de aplicar uma SeekBar para alterar os valores das variaveis **thresholdCanny** e **thresholdCanny2** diretamente no aplicativo em execução, ou seja, ajustar a intensidade dos filtros.

Segue minha função já com a SeekBar implementada:

```
    public Mat onCameraFrame(final CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

    // Image Processing
    Mat rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    Mat edges = new Mat(rgba.size(), CV_8UC1);
    final int thresholdCanny = 80, thresholdCanny2 = 100;

    // SeekBar change value
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });


    try {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(rgba, edges, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 4);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(edges, edges, new Size(5,5), 30, 50);
        Canny(edges, edges, thresholdCanny, thresholdCanny2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    return edges;
}
```

É possível capturar o atual valor de **thresholdCanny** e **thresholdCanny2** dentro da `onProgressChanged` e ir substituindo os valores dessas variáveis de acordo com o movimento da SeekBar? Como posso fazer isso?

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você obter o valor do **SeekBar**:

```
seekBar.getProgress();
```

E dentro do método `onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b)` o progresso é o segundo parâmetro `int progress`

E para trocar os valores de `final int thresholdCanny = 80, thresholdCanny2 = 100;` você pode criar essas variáveis no escopo de classe:

```
private int thresholdCanny = 80;
private int thresholdCanny2 = 100;
```

Comment: Devo utilizar thresholdCanny = seekBar.getProgress(); ?
Uma outra duvida, é possível fazer com que essa variável assuma um valor com algum outro calculo?  exemplo:  thresholdCanny - 20 // 
Obrigado

Comment: Pode fazer thresholdCanny = progress;

Comment: Nesse caso você pode criar um método `setThresholdCanny(int thresholdCanny)` e fazer o cálculo no método. E em vez de usar `thresholdCanny = progress;` você faz `setThresholdCanny(progress)`;. Assim fica mais flexível para criar cálculos etc.

Comment: Consegui, obrigado pela ajuda!